# Efficient data structure for insertion, deletion and search

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, data-structures

I need to keep track of open and closed states as certain resources are used. The first structure I have used are two `open_states_list` and `closed_states_list` to which I add and remove as states are updated.

- Inserting is O(1) if we ignore the internal memory allocation and reallocation mechanism, I guess: `open_states_list.append(x)`.
- Deleting is O(n): `open_states_list.remove(x)`.
- Searching, just like deleting, is O(n): `x in open_states_list`.
- Getting the list is obviously O(1).

The second structure I have used is a single dictionary with boolean values `open_states = {}` where if `open_states[x]` is `True` then `x` is open and if it is `False` then it is closed.

- "Inserting" is O(1) as we are just setting a key and a value: `open_states[x] = True`.
- "Deleting" is O(1) for the same reason: `open_states[x] = False`.
- "Searching" is also O(1), just accessing the value of the key: `open_states[x]`.
- Getting the list is O(n): `[x for x, s in open_states.iteritems() if s]`.

Our most common operation is checking whether `x` is open or not (search), so the second option is better. But our second most common operation, getting the lists of open or used states, follows the search operation very closely, is more efficiently in the first option. We cannot choose the first option though, because checking the state of a resource is O(n).

Inserting is very common too. Removing is not as essential.

What would be the most efficient data structure for these needs?

Comment: Why not a `set`? You don't really need a `dict` if the value is only going to be `True/False`, simply the presence/absence of the item can indicate it's state.

Comment: @CoryKramer I forgot to mention that the order is important. Would an `OrderedSet` be efficient as well? And is the set presence operation more efficient than the list?

Comment: @dabadaba python sets hash their contents (which is why you can't add unhashable items to a set) so the membership test should just be the cost of the hashing function and table lookup O(1). Don't know about OrderedSet.

Comment: @dabadaba check this [OrderedSet recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/). Should be what you need.

Comment: @JaredSmith I am testing this: `d = {x: 1 for x in range(1000000)}` and `o = OrderedSet(d)`. Then an element `e = 45462`. `%timeit e in d` averages 33.9 ns per loop, while `%timeit e in o` averages 190 ns per loop.

Comment: @JaredSmith also, while being an **ordered** collection, there's no way of accessing the ith element. In my case, I do need to access i.e. the first element.

Comment: @dabadaba in that case I guess you'll have to use a hashing structure for quick membership test combined with an indexed structure for order/index retrieval. I'm not sure you can get by here with one data structure. It'll make deletions a pain, but you said that's not important/common?

Comment: @JaredSmith not important in the sense of performance because they are less common so a suboptimal O wouldn't hurt, but they *are* important in the sense that they need to be consistent to the states. Why do you think it'd be a pain? It'd be a matter of updating the list and setting the state to `False`, I don't see how it's any different than the other operations, maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174038/discussion-between-jared-smith-and-dabadaba).

Comment: A terminology note: accessing something by key is usually called "lookup", rather than "search". The term "search" usually means getting a list of items that meet some criteria.